# How to use Ember Data serializer wth JQuery AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js

I've been using Ember-Data very well where my API endpoints are like

`domain.com/apples/`      => list of apples

`domain.com/apples/1/`    => Apple with id 1

`domain.com/worms/`       => list of worms

I need to fetch all the worms in one apple. My API endpoint for this is like

`domain.com/apples/1/worms/`    => list of worms in apple with id 1

I've been fetching those worms with `Em.$.getJSON(...)` and works fine. But the result is a list of Object and I want a list of Worm (*defined in /models/worms.js*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ember-api-actions](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions).

Your model will then look like this:

```
// app/models/apple.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { memberAction } from 'ember-api-actions';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  // GET /apples/:id/worms
  worms: memberAction({ path: 'worms', type: 'get' })
});
```

To fetch all worms for a given apple, use something like this:

```
this.store.findRecord('apple', params.id).then((apple) => apple.worms())
```

P.S. It's also possible to manually push the JSON response to the ember data store but implementing a custom adapter is more robust (something which you can see is made ridiculously easy by ember-data-actions)

Comment: You've undestood exactly what I need. Thanks!